# Insert a Date as a String to Access using a DAO Recordset

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datetime, dao, recordset

I am using some code I found in an old C# post to run a DAO insert into Access with VB.net. I ran the code to insert numbers and it ran fine. However When i try to insert a `date` as a string between hashes I get a `Data type conversion error`. I have had a look and I can't see how to change the data type of the recordset field to accept a string/date.

Here is the code:

```
    Dim dbEngine As New dao.DBEngine
    Dim db As dao.Database = dbEngine.OpenDatabase(DataDirectoryName & DatabaseName)
    Dim rs As dao.Recordset = db.OpenRecordset(TableName)

    Dim myFields As dao.Field() = New dao.Field(FieldNames.Count - 1) {}
    For k As Integer = 0 To FieldNames.Count - 1
        myFields(k) = rs.Fields(FieldNames(k))
    Next

    dbEngine.BeginTrans()
    For i As Double = 0 To Data.Rows - 1
        rs.AddNew()
        For k As Integer = 0 To FieldNames.Count - 1
            rs.Fields(k).Value = Data.Value(k, i)
            rs.Fields(FieldNames(k)).Value = Data.Value(k, i)
            myFields(k).Value = Data.Value(k, i)
        Next
        rs.Update()
    Next
    dbEngine.CommitTrans()
    rs.Close()
    db.Close()
```

Here is one row of data:

```
(0) = "74"
(1) = "#01 February 2012 00:02:00#"
(2) = "40"
(3) = "130"
(4) = "60"
```

'Data' is a custom class that is a `list (of list (of string))`.

Comment: DAO requires dates in the format #mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss# (the year can also be 2 characters). Reformat the date and you should be fine.

Comment: @Ciarán I have tried both #mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss# and '#mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss#', both give the same error as before.

Comment: @Remou The "" delimiters are from vb.net showing this as a string, I dont believe these are sent to the DB, and don't know how I would remove them. As in the previous comment I have tried both with date and string delimiters and with only date delimiters, but still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While VBA will accept date delimiters on your string, eg #11 February 2013 20:23:11# it seems that VB.Net will not, however, it does accept for an MS Access update.

```
 rs.Fields("adate").Value = CDate("11 February 2013 20:23:11")
```